# Discord.js send emoji

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to make my bot send an emoji whenever I Type `=emoji`

I've managed to get everything done but I have no idea how to make the bot send an emoji by the ID of the emoji.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you share what you've already done?

Comment: Also; this seems to be what you want to do? https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/reactions.html#reacting-to-messages

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do you know the name of the emoji? if so, you can simply do this:

```js
message.channel.send("<:emoji name:emoji id>")
```

If not, you could possibly do,

```js
const emoji = bot.emojis.cache.get("emoji id")

message.channel.send(`${emoji}`)
```

I assume the emoji has to be cached for the method above to work, i'm sure someone else could brew up a better solution.

Hope i could help!

Comment: It's really hard to understand where should I replace with the emoji name... Maybe elaborate more on your answer?

Answer (score 4):

For an animated emoji use
`<a:EmojiName:EmojiID>`

If you don't have Nitro to check the emoji's ID check the guide [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/discordapp/comments/ifd2bf/get_animated_emoji_id_without_nitro/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
message.channel.send(":emoji name:emoji id")
```

For if you know the name or the emoji you want

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the format has been changed now.

I was able to get it using
`message.channel.send("Hey! :smiley:")`
Just like that!

Comment: Perhaps it is different for built-in vs. custom emojis.